# Codeigniter force_download() does not work for PDF extensions

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm facing two problems.

1. force_download() does not work for pdf extensions.

when I try to download a txt extension file the functions work fine 
**below code.**

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = "some text";
        $name = "sample.txt";
        force_download($name,$data);
    }
```

but when I try to do it with a pdf extension, the file gets downloaded properly but when I click the downloaded pdf file it shows Error: **Failed to load PDF document.**

```
public function index()
        {
            $data = "some text for pdf";
            $name = "sample.pdf";
            force_download($name,$data);
        }
```

2. **secondly is there a way to ask or show a dialogue box before downloading a file instead of force download.**

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create a (not currupt) pdf file with `force_download()`. You'll need to create the pdf file using a php library like [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) or similar. The `force_download()` function only **generates a header** which forces a download to happen.

If the pdf file exists on the server you can `force_download('/path/to/my_pdf.pdf', NULL);`

concerning the second part of your question, this is too broad, there are thousands of ways to create a dialog box

Comment: So we can generate only .txt extension file.

Answer (score 0):

pass name of the file you want to download

**Controller**

```
function download($file_name)
{
    $this->load->helper('download');
    force_download('./assets/'.$file_name, NULL);
}
```

**View**

```
<a href="<?php echo SURL.'controller_name/download/'.$file_name;?>">Download
</a>
```

For second question try **onclick()**