# ERROR Array to string conversion in Codeigniter when using unlink or force_download

Tags: php, codeigniter

i don't know why it cant be downloaded,
not only for download, but for unlink to has the same error.

this is for filecontroller:

```
public function openfile($name){
        $namea = array('file'=>$name);
        force_download('./upload/data/'.$namea,NULL);
    }
```

and this is for view:

```
<?php echo anchor('filecontroller/openfile/'.$data['name'], "download", array('class'=>"btn btn-success float-center"));?>
```

Comment: is this for pdf files?

Comment: yes, it is for pdf files

Comment: then please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51366988/2275490

Comment: but how about when i'm trying to unlink the file?

Comment: how are you using unlink? unlink returns a boolean (true||false), depending if deletion was successful or not

Comment: i'm using unlink to delete file from upload folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of your code:

```
public function openfile($name)
{
   $namea = array('file'=>$name);
   force_download('./upload/data/'.$namea,NULL);
}
```

you're passing an array (`$namea`) where the function (be it `force_download` or `unlink`) expects a string.

The first argument for `force_download` is a string with the path to the file you want to download. However, your code will evaluate to something like this:

`force_download('./upload/data/ARRAY', NULL);`

which is obviously not correct. You cannot concatenate an array with a string.

Try this:

```
public function openfile($name){
        $namea = array('file'=>$name);
        force_download('./upload/data/'.$namea['file'],NULL);
    }
```

This way, you're not trying to concatenate the string with the full array (the fact that it has only one element is irrelevant: it's still an array) but you're concatenating the string with the `file` array element, which will work fine